# WPF UI threading issue

Tags: wpf, thread-safety

I have a com visible static class ([STAThread]) that starts up a wpf window app.Run(MainWindow) within Main.  After the mainwindow starts there is a button to open another window called settings.  When an external app calls one of my com classes it starts up my com object and opens the mainwindow.  That's the behavior I want, so far so good!

The external app can also call an exposed method which starts my com object and opens the settings window directly.  I do this by using the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action) to the settings window.  When this happens it also opens the mainwindow because of the mainthread starting, which is okay.

My problem is when user shuts down the settings window.  The main window become non-responsive to clicks. Seems to me the mainwindow is running on a different thread and can't be accessed.

I hope I've explained this well enough to generate some ideas.  If not let me know what I can post to help out.  The code jumps around a lot for this so it's kinda hard to post everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Log the name/id of the thread that opens the main window. Then, debug the application, close the settings window to make the main window unresponsive, hit break/pause in Visual studio and check what that logged thread is doing. (to switch to that thread add the Debug Location toolbar to Visual Studio)

Comment: To formulate a good answer to this, I'd need to see more exactly (rather than just a description) how the main window is invoked, and how the settings window is invoked. It sounds like either the dispatcher is becoming blocked, or the mainwindow is. If it was on a different thread, this wouldn't be the case, so it may be an issue with which thread is doing what (which SO may be able to troubleshoot, with more detail)

Comment: I'll see if I can setup some sample code and post another question, thanks